# How to hide GET variables, but keep value

Tags: php, get, hide

How would I go about doing something like this:

www.website.com/process.php?ip=32.313.131.31

to

www.website.com/32.313.131.31

Answer (score 1):

Use a URL rewriting module. If you are using Apache, mod_rewrite is the tool for the job. In your case, a rule like this should suffice:

```
RewriteRule ^/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) /process.php?ip=$1
```

If you want a more general rule that doesn't just match IP addresses, it becomes trickier, because you don't want the rule to match the rewritten form, in case it is inadvertently specified in a link somewhere (e.g., you don't want `www.website.com/process.php?ip=32.313.131.31` to be rewritten as `www.website.com/process.php?ip=process.php?ip=32.313.131.31`).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Apache, so you could use mod_rewrite to achieve this. Create a `.htaccess` file in your document root directory and create a rewrite rule to pass all requests that look like IP addresses to process.php. Something like this should do:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$ /process.php?ip=$1 [NC]
```